# Is there a plugin in vscode to easily view netcdf files?

Tags: visual-studio-code, visualization, netcdf

Does such a plugin exist ?
It would open the `.nc` files using that extenstion, as vscode is capable for other kind of files.

I would be happy with something similar to
[the xarray.Dataset output in the python interactive mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMqVz.png)

Or something more fancy where we could also plot the data.

Comment: if you can't find one on the Market place you can write one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another suggestion, which I found meanwhile is h5web:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=h5web.vscode-h5web

It has a neat UI to pick the dimensions and variables you want to inspect and even sliders to slide through additional dimensions. I wasn't able to open any .nc file that came a cross, but most of the times it worked for me.

Answer (score -2):

Check this: it allows to have all info about the netcdf file although you cannot display it (e.g. ncview)
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Feliks.ncpreview